# Subtraction not working in compass scss

Tags: sass, compass-sass

While ive been loving [compass](http://compass-style.org), I just ran to a confusing issue. I'm trying to subtract one from a value like this:

```
padding-left:($top-bar-padding*4)-1;
padding-left:($top-bar-padding*4-1);
padding-left:($top-bar-padding*4)-1px;
padding-left:($top-bar-padding*4-1px);
```

I've tried all of those and they all give me:

```
padding-left: 20px -1px;
```

It really puzzling me because I have this earlier in the `.scss` file and it is working fine:

```
padding:$top-bar-padding*2+2 $top-bar-padding*4;
```

Any insights on why this is happening?

Comment: Maybe you can post your update as an answer and accept it?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You need to have a **space before and after** the **subtraction** symbol like this:

```
($top-bar-padding*4 - 1)
```

Comment: at college we were taught hyphens aren't used in variable names for this reason, though this advice seems to have been ignored by css authors. The result ? This confusing problem, the old school guys are often right !